# how to publish an update to application on the android market?

Tags: android

I already have an application on the android market and now I want to upload an update to that application.
I have made the new application with the same package name, I have incremented the version code and name , I have signed with the same key-store...etc. Now I want to know how to publish an update.

Do I upload the update as a separate application? or how else do I do it?

EDIT: Does the apk name need to be same as the previous version? I mean if my apk name for the original version is abc.apk can my update name be xyz.apk?

Comment: Yes, your apk name must be the same as the previous version.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to upload your new app as the same app as previous version except you need to increment the version number in manifest xml.

So if you have manifest file like following:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
          android:versionCode="1"  
    . . .  
</manifest>
```

You will need following:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
          android:versionCode="2"  
    . . .  
</manifest>
```

Comment: what do i do once i have logged onto the android market? i know all the pre-requisites....like increasing the version no. etc....

Comment: You just need to go to your app page on the developer console and you will see upload section where you can upload your new version app.

Comment: why are you not understanding . i have done all the above. i need to know once i have done this , do i need to upload my new app as a separate app on the android market.

Comment: There is a link called [Upload upgrade]

Comment: As I said go to your app page (This implies you are not creating separate app) and upload your new app.

Comment: i tried doing that , but it just says that .apk saved. does that mean it has published the upgrade?

Comment: You do not need to create separate app.

Comment: After you uploaded it, do you see save or publish button at the bottom?

Comment: ok, thanks. do i need to do anything special for all the clients to receive update notification or is this automatic?

Comment: If you see publish please click that, else please click save. Then it should be upgraded. You might want to check it on the market if it is really updated.

Comment: I think the updated notification is handled automatically as long as users enable "notify me when there is upgrades" option.

Comment: But i want to know that, Should i able to Update the My recent uploaded version application ? I mean i just want to change some of the class file of that Application. So Should i able to do it ??

Answer (score 11):

@knoguchi is rite.

for that you should:

1) Unpublished app from market(**Your published apk can't delete it will be deactive only.**)

2) after that in you Latest menifest add

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
. . .
</manifest>
```

You will need following:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.1"
. . .
</manifest>
```

3) And sign again your apk from eclipde->Android tools->Export singed application package-> sign it->

4) Upload that Apk to market.

Hope it will help.

Comment: This response is more complete

Comment: I know android documentation clearly say to update version code with every release. But I want to know what is with versionName? does this value needs to get updated on every release.

Comment: This is the most complete answer, yes!

Comment: Do we need to do something to tell users that new version is available on Play store ?

Answer (score 10):

Might be too late but:
Once you're logged into the Android market for publishers, click on your app under "All Android Market listings", and click on the tab "APK files".
Then you need to deactivate the current published apk version (click on "deactivate"), upload your new APK (click on "upload APK"), activate it (click on "activate"), and click on "save".
You don't need to unpublish-publish at all (if all you want to do is update your apk).

So, you don't need to upload your app as a new app, you just update the existing one.

**Note**: You can't delete the older versions of your apk, they're staying there for you to be able to reactivate one of them is need be.

Comment: I did what you told. But I am not getting the update notification. how long does it take after saving the new apk to get the notification.

Comment: Do we need to do something to tell users that new version is available on Play store ?

Answer (score 1):

To upload an update first of all make changes in Android Manifest as described in other answers.
Then go to Home screen of Google Play Developer Console. Click on app whose update you have to upload in "All Applications" section. On left panel list, there will be options for APK, Store Listing, Pricing and Distribution,etc.
Go to APK section. There in center you will find button "Upload new APK to Production".
Thats It! Upload your new version of App and click Publish.