# I Open Android Studio For Update My App After Generate Sign APK (What I do with these 2 files)

Tags: android

I generate sign APK and published it successfully.

When I open my Android studio again. My project open and when I click on RUN then this window opens : http://prntscr.com/gn2dt7 Don't know what I write in these fields?
And When I click the fix then this window opens : http://prntscr.com/gn2gvu also don't know what I write in these fields?

Guide Me Please About These Two Files.

Comment: I bet there are hundreds of tutorials out there exactly for this purpose.

Comment: For example looks at this question and various existing ones at stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5700565

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to publish an update to application on the android market?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700565/how-to-publish-an-update-to-application-on-the-android-market)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to run the project once again, before making it as a signed apk **change the version name and version number in build.gradle**, then go to the playstore where you have published your previous signed apk, at the same place click again to upload apk and publish it. After uploading the apk it shows the update in playstore(it takes some time to show the button update).

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the versionCode (this be always a number and must self-increase) and the versionName in the gradle, after that you only need to build de apk.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience it is good to create one `key file` for every application you will create and you must take care of it .

When you publish new `APK file` from your project you must change only `version number` and `version name`  , but you must use existing `key file`that you created it before  to sign your application's new version .

Comment: when you edit a question, do not format random words as code, such as `app` and `update`

Comment: @TimCastelijns what is correct format for these words ?

Comment: but these are not simple words and the words like APK must have special format

Comment: You don't need 1 key per application.  1 key per developer is sufficient, and has advantages (applications signed by the same key can interact in way those signed by different keys can't).

Comment: And no, words like APK do not get special format on this site.